# Hibernate get action cause an update action

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

We use HibernateTemplate to get an object, but it cause an update action.Our database are read-only, because we don't need to update data.

Why that happen? Please Help me..

My code:

```
  public <T> T get(Class<T> clasz, Serializable id) {
    return (T) getHibernateTemplate().get(clasz, id);
```

}

The error message as follow:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: Hibernate operation: Could not execute JDBC batch update; uncategorized SQLException for SQL [update kytv_resource_station set area=?, create_id=?, create_time=?, display=?, modify_id=?, modify_time=?, nature=?, partner=?, showDomain=?, status=?, tv_character=?, tv_desc=?, tv_elogo=?, tv_elogo_id=?, tv_keyword=?, tv_logo=?, tv_logo_id=?, tv_name=?, tv_order=?, tv_short_name=?, tv_show_name=?, tv_tvm_name=? where id=?]; SQL state [HY000]; error code [1290]; The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement; nested exception is java.sql.BatchUpdateException: The MySQL server is running with the --read-only option so it cannot execute this statement
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:124)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:322)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertJdbcAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:424)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateAccessor.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateAccessor.java:410)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:424)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.get(HibernateTemplate.java:522)
        at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.get(HibernateTemplate.java:516)
```

Comment: What hibernate query are you using for this operation. Write it so that `code` problem could be seen!!

Answer (score 0):

Your program has error because of this query

```
  update kytv_resource_station set area=?, create_id=?, create_time=?, display=?, modify_id=?, modify_time=?, nature=?, partner=?, showDomain=?, status=?, tv_character=?, tv_desc=?, tv_elogo=?, tv_elogo_id=?, tv_keyword=?, tv_logo=?, tv_logo_id=?, tv_name=?, tv_order=?, tv_short_name=?, tv_show_name=?, tv_tvm_name=? where id=?
```

Your program displays MySql Error 1290, in mysql documentation it means

```
  The MySQL server is running with the %s option so it cannot execute this statement.
```

You mean `Our database are read-only`, so why do you make update operation.If you need correct answer, post your code with edit question.

Comment: i don't make any update operation,i just get an object use HibernateTemplate's get methord. But the query action cause update operation,i don't know why.

Comment: @user1637794 Try SessionFactory instead of Hibernate Template.It is the best way.